# Duplicate script tags renders first tag but not the second using ExtJS

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, extjs

I'm getting strange behaviour that causes ExtJS to not load the second tag of 2 script tags. I'm using tabPanel.update('text here', true) which causes the first script tag to execute but not the second.

I've done a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/kum6p94g/ which proves you can use 2 script tags with ExtJS.Ajax however I could not get a working example of the `tabsPanel.update(..., true)`. Maybe someone else can start and I'll replicate that way.

Can anyone help?

*EDIT*

See https://jsfiddle.net/f4q6rz9p/ for this behaviour, the script tags only execute one time, despite there being 2 script tags.

However, interestingly, it works when you add '+' before the / of script end tag, causing the browser not to see the end tag markup. See here https://jsfiddle.net/f4q6rz9p/1/